# Get non-overlapping distinct intervals from a set of intervals Python

Tags: python, intervals, overlapping

Given a set of intervals, I would like to find non-overlapping distinct intervals from a set of intervals.

For example:

Input: `[[1,10], [5,20], [6,21], [17,25], [22,23], [24,50] ,[30,55], [60,70]]`

Output: `[[1,5], [21,22], [23,24], [25,30], [50,55], [60,70]]`

How can I do that?

What I have currently tried:

```
gene_bounds_list = [[1,10],[5,20], [6,21],[17,25],[22,23], [24,50],[30,55],[60,70]]
overlap_list = []
nonoverlap_list = []
nonoverlap_list.append(gene_bounds_list[0])

for i in range(1, len(gene_bounds_list)):
    curr_gene_bounds = gene_bounds_list[i]
    prev_gene_bounds = nonoverlap_list[-1]

    if curr_gene_bounds[0]<prev_gene_bounds[0]:
        if curr_gene_bounds[1]<prev_gene_bounds[0]: #case1
            continue
        if curr_gene_bounds[1] < prev_gene_bounds[1]:  #case2
            nonoverlap_list[-1][0] = curr_gene_bounds[1]
        if curr_gene_bounds[1]>prev_gene_bounds[1]:
            # previous gene was completely overlapping within current gene,
            # so replace previous gene by current (bigger) gene and put previous gene into overlap list
            overlap_list.append(nonoverlap_list[-1])
            new_bound = [gene_bounds_list[i][0], gene_bounds_list[i][1]]
            nonoverlap_list.pop()
            nonoverlap_list.append([new_bound[0], new_bound[1]])

    elif curr_gene_bounds[0] > prev_gene_bounds[0] and curr_gene_bounds[1] < prev_gene_bounds[1]:
        # completely within another gene
        overlap_list.append([curr_gene_bounds[0], curr_gene_bounds[1]])

    elif curr_gene_bounds[0] < prev_gene_bounds[1]:
        # partially overlapping with another gene
        new_bound = [nonoverlap_list[-1][1], curr_gene_bounds[1]]
        nonoverlap_list[-1][1] = curr_gene_bounds[0]
        nonoverlap_list.append([new_bound[0], new_bound[1]])

    else:
        # not overlapping with another gene
        nonoverlap_list.append([gene_bounds_list[i][0], gene_bounds_list[i][1]])

unique_data = [list(x) for x in set(tuple(x) for x in gene_bounds_list)]
within_overlapping_intervals = []

for small in overlap_list:
    for master in unique_data:
        if (small[0]==master[0] and small[1]==master[1]):
            continue
        if (small[0]>master[0] and small[1]<master[1]):
            if(small not in within_overlapping_intervals):
                within_overlapping_intervals.append([small[0], small[1]])

for o in within_overlapping_intervals:
    nonoverlap_list.append(o)  # append the overlapping intervals

nonoverlap_list.sort(key=lambda tup: tup[0])
flat_data = sorted([x for sublist in nonoverlap_list for x in sublist])
new_gene_intervals = [flat_data[i:i + 2] for i in range(0, len(flat_data), 2)]
print(new_gene_intervals)
```

However, this gives me an output of: `[[1, 5], [6, 10], [17, 20], [21, 22], [23, 24], [25, 30], [50, 55], [60, 70]]`

Any ideas of how I can remove the unwanted intervals?

Comment: what is the value of the maximum and minimum interval you can have? I mean what is the range of the intervals?

Comment: Range of the whole range the starting value of the first interval and ending value of the last interval. In this case, the range of the intervals is [1,70].

Comment: It is for this input. I meant for all inputs.

Comment: How big can the interval get? A brute force might work if instead of 70 it doesn't go say beyond 10,000

Comment: All inputs would be within the [1,50000000] range. 
A brute force solution would also be fine.

Comment: Are you looking for something different from [Maximally Disjoint Intervals](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximal-disjoint-intervals/)?  But, it provides a different answer for you test case i.e. `[[ 1 ,  10 ],
[ 22 ,  23 ],
[ 24 ,  50 ],
[ 60 ,  70 ]]`

Comment: Yes, what I am looking for is different from maximally disjoint intervals.
Eg, `Input = [[1, 4], [2, 3], [4, 6], [8, 9]]`

In maximally disjoint intervals, they output all the intervals that are disjoint from each other. `Output: [[2, 3], [4, 6], [8, 9]]`

What I want can be imagined as collapsing all the intervals on a number line, and only get those intervals, which do not overlap with any other intervals. `Output: [[1,2], [3,4], [4,6], [8,9]]`

Comment: I think I understand what you want.  However, maximally disjoint is different from your description.  It generates a maximally set of disjoint intervals that cover the span of original intervals [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_disjoint_set#1-dimensional_intervals:_exact_polynomial_algorithm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to do it. The idea is to keep track of the number of layers of intervals at any point. For this, we add one layer when entering an interval, and remove one when exiting.

We start by building sorted lists of starts and ends.  In order to identify the if a value is a start or an end, we create tuples `(start, 1)` or `(end, -1)`.

Then, we  merge these two lists, sorting by value, and iterate over the resulting list (using [heapq.merge](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#heapq.merge) makes this easy). 
Each time the number of layers changes to 1, we have the start of a non-overlapping interval. When it changes again, it's the end of it.

```
from heapq import merge


def non_overlapping(data):
    out = []
    starts = sorted([(i[0], 1) for i in data])  # start of interval adds a layer of overlap
    ends = sorted([(i[1], -1) for i in data])   # end removes one
    layers = 0
    current = []
    for value, event in merge(starts, ends):    # sorted by value, then ends (-1) before starts (1)
        layers += event
        if layers ==1:  # start of a new non-overlapping interval
            current.append(value)
        elif current:  # we either got out of an interval, or started an overlap
            current.append(value)
            out.append(current)
            current = []
    return out


data = [[1,10], [5,20], [6,21], [17,25], [22,23], [24,50] ,[30,55], [60,70]]

non_overlapping(data)
# [[1, 5], [21, 22], [23, 24], [25, 30], [50, 55], [60, 70]]
```

Note that the expected answer you put in your question is wrong (for example, it contains a 45 that isn't part of the input data)

Comment: Thanks. This indeed solves it. :)
I have edited the example output in my question to remove the error.

Answer (score 1):

Plot the intervals on a timeline. As the range is just `10**5`, we can use the memory. Plotting and scanning can be done in linear time.

```
intervals = [[1,10], [5,20], [6,21], [17,25], [22,23], [24,50] ,[30,55], [60,70]]

max_ = max(intervals, key=lambda x: x[1])[1]
timeline = [0] * (max_ + 1)

# mark plots
for start, end in intervals:
    timeline[start] += 1
    timeline[end] -= 1


# make the timeline
for i in range(1, len(timeline)):
    timeline[i] += timeline[i - 1]


# scan
result = []
for i, item in enumerate(timeline):
    if i == 0:
        continue
    prev = timeline[i - 1]
    if item == 1 and prev != 1:
        result.append([i, i + 1])
    elif item == 1 and prev == 1:
        result[-1][1] = i + 1
        end = i


print(result)
```

EDIT:
As the range is updated to ~`10^8`, this won't work.

Comment: As you justly noted, that wouldn't be practical for large ranges, and wouldn't be possible at all if we have floats.